# Azure website deployment - .Net website

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, azure-web-app-service, kentico, azure-deployment

I'm doing a web site deployment in azure with bit bucket source.
When I do the deployments I can see always its building the source,
Actually that is not required to me, because it is a Kentico 10 web site (.Net website project).

How do i avoid building while source deployment/ pull the latest from bitbuckt ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should stop using continuous integration process in bitbucket and hook your own process to do a xcopy (preferably delta) to target website folder.

Answer (score 0):

Using the OOB tools it is not possible to deploy without a build. So you can do a few things:

- FTP
- Visual Studio publish
- command line copy after a successful build locally.

Another setup could reduce the number of builds you have when deploying but will still build the solution, more branches in Bitbucket.
You could continue to use CI but make sure you hook your environments to proper branches so they only deploy when you perform a merge into that branch.

Answer (score 0):

> How do i avoid building while source deployment/ pull the latest from bitbuckt ?

You could check the deployment details under "DEPLOYMENT > Deployment options" as follows:

[image]

And you could leverage [KUDU](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) and check the auto-generated `deploy.cmd` file under `D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd`.

For your requirement, I would recommend you customize your `deploy.cmd` file, and put `.deployment` and `deploy.cmd` files into your Bitbucket repository. For a simple way, you could just download your current deployment script and modify the scripts under the Deployment section, you need to remove the script for building your solution and just leave the script for kudu sync, and you need to modify the value for the `-f` option from `"%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%"` to `"%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%"` when invoking the `%KUDU_SYNC_COMMAND%`. Details you could follow [Custom Deployment Script](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Custom-Deployment-Script).

Comment: You could do this, but you can shortcut things using `SCM_SCRIPT_GENERATOR_ARGS`. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deploy the full content of your repo with no build or transformation at all, just set `SCM_SCRIPT_GENERATOR_ARGS=--basic` in the Azure App Settings. This will force the script generator to treat is as a 'basic' site, and won't do any build.

See [wiki](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#taking-over-the-script-generator-command-line) for more info.